# Notice: Undefined index: MM_Username

Tags: php

-IF THIS IS GOING TO BE DOWNVOTED SO BE IT, I JUST NEED THE HELP-

I am creating my own CMS and after lots of hours I finally got it to where I could display log in when no user is logged in and logout when a user is logged in. However now I get this error ONLY when user is not logged in

> Notice: Undefined index: MM_Username in C:\wamp\www...\header.php on line 43
>
> Notice: Undefined index: MM_Username in C:\wamp\www...\header.php on line 45

here is my entire header.php (Its just the code for the top nav bar)

```
<?php
//initialize the session
if (!isset($_SESSION)) {
  session_start();
}

// ** Logout the current user. **
$logoutAction = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."?doLogout=true";
if ((isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) && ($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] != "")){
  $logoutAction .="&". htmlentities($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
}

if ((isset($_GET['doLogout'])) &&($_GET['doLogout']=="true")){
  //to fully log out a visitor we need to clear the session varialbles
  $_SESSION['MM_Username'] = NULL;
  $_SESSION['MM_UserGroup'] = NULL;
  $_SESSION['PrevUrl'] = NULL;
  unset($_SESSION['MM_Username']);
  unset($_SESSION['MM_UserGroup']);
  unset($_SESSION['PrevUrl']);

  $logoutGoTo = "admin/login.php";
  if ($logoutGoTo) {
    header("Location: $logoutGoTo");
    exit;
  }
}
?>
<nav class="top-bar">
    <ul class="title-area">
      <li class="name"><h1><a href="#">Robdogga55's Paradise [BETA]</a></h1></li>
    </ul>
    <section class="top-bar-section">
      <ul class="left">
        <li><a href="/"><img src="images/icons/home_icon.png"> Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="page_about_1.html"><img src="images/icons/about_icon.png"> About</a></li>
        <li><a href="page_showcase_2.html"><img src="images/icons/pages_icon.png"> Showcase</a></li>
        <li><a href="page_videos_5.html"><img src="images/icons/videos_icon.png"> Videos</a></li>
        <li>Welcome <?php echo $row_Recordset1['username']; ?>!</li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="right">

<?php if ($_SESSION['MM_Username'] != '') { ?>
<li><a href="<?php echo $logoutAction ?>"><img src="images/icons/login_icon.png"> Logout</a></li>
<?php } elseif ($_SESSION['MM_Username'] == '') { ?>
<li><a href="admin/"><img src="images/icons/login_icon.png"> Log in</a></li>
<?php } ?>

      </ul>
    </section>
</nav>
```

Any help would be great, thanks. It's probably something simple I am not seeing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have unset the MM_Username item with: `unset($_SESSION['MM_Username']);` the `MM_Username` key no longer exists and you obtain an error when you try to access it in line 43 with `$_SESSION['MM_Username`]`

I suggest you to comment (or remove, or move after) : `unset($_SESSION['MM_Username']);` and test the existence of this index with `if (isset($_SESSION['MM_Username']))` before using it.

Comment: I tried that one the `<?php if ($_SESSION['MM_Username'] != '') { ?>` line (replacing it with `if (isset($_SESSION['MM_Username']))`) and one error goes away but then I tried to do the same to the elseif line and now no errors but then `<li><a href="admin/"><img src="images/icons/login_icon.png"> Log in</a></li>` doesn't get shown

Comment: @Robdogga55: You don't need to replace the if and elseif condition (however it is better to write `elseif (empty($_SESSION['MM_Username']))` cause it's more explicit/readable). You must test the existence of `$_SESSION['MM_Username']` before the if condition and put all the paragraph between curly brackets

Answer (score 0):

Replace line 43 and line 45 as following:

```
<?php if (isset($_SESSION['MM_Username'])) { ?>
```

And

```
<?php } elseif (isset($_SESSION['MM_Username'])) { ?>
```

Comment: This seems to remove the log in part altogether